# What is the point of no side effects if I need 3 loops instead of one to do it?

Tags: javascript, side-effects

Imagine I have a list of objects that are Questions. I have to find if they are visible and if they are visible I have to change their answer to visible as well. (The example may not be practical it is just an example)
If this is no side effect way (is it?):

```
questions.filter(function(question) {
    return question.isVisible;
})
.map(function(visibleQuestion) {
    return getAnswer(visibleQuestion);
})
.map(function(answer) {
    answer.isVisible = true;
});
```

and this is side effect way:

```
questions.forEach(function(question) {
    if (question.isVisible) {
        var answer = getAnswer(visibleQuestion);
        answer.isVisible = true;
    }
});
```

Why choose the no side effect way if you have to iterate 3 times to do your job?

PS. I could be wrong of what is side effect and what is not and what really would be the two ways of handling this.

Comment: I think that if you were using purely side-effect-free code, you wouldn't return the original `answer`; you would return a copy of the original answer but with `isVisible` set to `true`. In this case, it doesn't make sense to go through hoops to avoid side effects.

Comment: And if JS's `map` and `filter` are lazy, you're actually only iterating once.

Comment: And as Zev mentioned, you're carrying out side effects anyways in your second `map`, so you're forcing functional style but adhering to imperative practices. The 2 don't mix well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument against callbacks and side effects is about maintainability and reclaiming the call stack so we can use keywords like `throw` and `return`.

The example you provided certainly makes it seem like an easy engineering trade off between readability and efficiency. That being said using a promise library you can achieve the same results without a callback/side effect all in a single loop.

```
promise.all(questions.map(function(question) {
        if (question.isVisible) {
            resolve(getAnswer(question));
        }
    }).then(function (arResults) {
        arResults.forEach(function(answer) {
            answer.isVisible = true;
            console.log(answer)
        });
    });
```